# Iterative copying (cloning) of a N-ary tree

Tags: java, kotlin, recursion, data-structures, tree

How to clone/copy N-ary tree iteratively, without recursion? Just need to rewrite `cloneRecursive` function iteratively:

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque

sealed class Row {

    abstract val name: String

    data class Section(override val name: String, val rows: List<Row>) : Row()

    data class Field(override val name: String, val data: String) : Row()
}

fun main() {
    val root = Row.Section(
        "root", listOf(
            Row.Section(
                "section 1", listOf(
                    Row.Section(
                        "section 1.1", listOf(
                            Row.Field("field 1.1.1", "1.1.1 - 1"),
                            Row.Field("field 1.1.2", "1.1.2 - 1")
                        )
                    ),
                    Row.Field("field 1.2", "1.2 - 1")
                )
            ),
            Row.Field("field 2", "2 - 1"),
            Row.Field("field 3", "3 - 1"),
            Row.Section(
                "section 4", listOf(
                    Row.Field("field 4.1", "4.1 - 1"),
                    Row.Field("field 4.2", "4.2 - 1"),
                    Row.Section(
                        "section 4.3", listOf(
                            Row.Field("field 4.3.1", "4.3.1 - 1"),
                            Row.Field("field 4.3.2", "4.3.2 - 1")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )

    println(root)
    println(recursiveClone(root))
    println(root == recursiveClone(root))
}

fun recursiveClone(root: Row): Row {
    return when (root) {
        is Row.Section -> {
            val rows = root.rows.map { row ->
                recursiveClone(row)
            }
            Row.Section(root.name, rows)
        }
        is Row.Field -> {
            Row.Field(root.name, root.data)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the context and motivation a bit? This is a challenging problem as-is, but also kind of pointless because you are using purely immutable classes and properties. Can you modify the classes?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I just need to do transformation based on source tree. For example deserialize hierarchical JSON into tree object. Cloning is just a simple example of such transformation. That's the point - I want to have iterative algorithm which makes deep immutable tree clones. For dealing with immutability need to clone using postorder traversing, where root node is last visiting node.

Comment: The question seems legitimate and I don't think it's unduly challenging (you can use an explicit stack instead of the implicit call stack). Would you accept an answer in Java? I'm not familiar with Kotlin.

Comment: @ggorlen Sure. Java is great variant :)

Comment: @ggorlen "challenging" is relative--it's definitely possible. I'm interested in seeing solutions to this and how concise or clear they can be. I started trying to do it with a stack but saw that it would take more than a single collection to do it my way.

Comment: Probably its a hard problem, as it does not follow the tail-recursive style, since mapping is not direct return task, so will be somewhat hard to implement.

Comment: Yeah, a second stack seems necessary. It's definitely less trivial than recursion, but no means unduly challenging, unless I'm missing something obvious (it's been known to happen!). And yes, challenging is certainly relative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach you could try is creating a couple of stacks. The only difference from a normal iterative tree traversal using a single stack and loop is a second stack that keeps references to parents so that children can be linked. Whenever a node is visited, pop the parent stack and add the current node to the parent's child list. Afterwards, when pushing children for the current node to extend the origin stack, push a reference to the current node onto the parent stack for each child. The two stacks will always be the same size.

This simulates the ease of building child trees using recursion and passing their clones back to the parent call to populate its children list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Stack;

class Main {
    public static Row clone(Row root) {
        if (root == null) return null;

        var originStack = new Stack<Row>();
        var parentStack = new Stack<Section>();
        originStack.push(root);
        parentStack.push(null);
        Row result = null;

        while (!originStack.isEmpty()) {
            Row curr = originStack.pop();
            Section parent = parentStack.pop();
            Row clone;

            if (curr instanceof Section) {
                clone = new Section(curr.name, new ArrayList<Row>());
                var sec = (Section)curr;

                for (int i = sec.children.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    originStack.push(sec.children.get(i));
                    parentStack.push((Section)clone);
                }
            }
            else {
                clone = new Field(curr.name, ((Field)curr).data);
            }

            if (parent == null) {
                result = clone;
            }
            else {
                parent.children.add(clone);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void print(Row root) {
        if (root != null) print(root, 0);
    }

    public static void print(Row root, int indent) {        
        for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        System.out.print(root.name);

        if (root instanceof Section) {
            System.out.println();

            for (Row child : ((Section)root).children) {
                print(child, indent + 2);
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(" [" + ((Field)root).data + "]");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var root = new Section(
            "a", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                new Section(
                    "b", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                        new Section(
                            "c", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                                new Field("d", "1")
                            ))
                        ),
                        new Section(
                            "e", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                                new Field("f", "2"),
                                new Section(
                                    "g", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                                        new Field("h", "3"),
                                        new Field("i", "4"),
                                        new Field("j", "5") 
                                    ))
                                )
                            ))
                        )
                    ))
                ),
                new Section(                    
                    "k", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                        new Section(
                            "l", new ArrayList<>()
                        ),
                        new Field("m", "6"),
                        new Field("n", "7"),
                        new Section(
                            "o", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                                new Field("p", "8")
                            ))
                        )
                    ))
                )
            ))
        );
        var clone = clone(root);
        ((Section)(((Section)clone).children.get(0)))
            .children.add(new Field("a new field", "42"));
        print(root);
        System.out.println("------------");
        print(clone);
        System.out.println("root is the same object as the clone: " + (root == clone));
    }
}

abstract class Row {
    String name;
}

final class Section extends Row {
    ArrayList<Row> children;

    public Section(String name, ArrayList<Row> children) {
        this.name = name;
        this.children = children;
    }
}

final class Field extends Row {
    String data;

    public Field(String name, String data) {
        this.name = name;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a
  b
    c
      d [1]
    e
      f [2]
      g
        h [3]
        i [4]
        j [5]
  k
    l
    m [6]
    n [7]
    o
      p [8]
------------
a
  b
    c
      d [1]
    e
      f [2]
      g
        h [3]
        i [4]
        j [5]
    a new field [42]
  k
    l
    m [6]
    n [7]
    o
      p [8]
root is the same object as the clone: false
```